# Swift detect keydown during app launch?

Tags: swift, xcode

In an xcode / Swift application, I'd like to detect if the app was launched with the (for example ) Shift key depressed.   Presumably this can be accomplished in the ViewController??

Comment: please consider adding more details, e.g. your code, your initial research, and whatever error messages thrown. that would be way easier for us to help

Comment: I don't have any useful code to share, I've got an app that runs perfectly well, but currently does not handle any keyboard events. I don't need to handle keyboard events on amy UI widget in the app, I just need to know if a meta key (Option, Control, Shift, etc.) was held down when the app was launched.  There are lots of example of handling keyboard events for UI widgets. But I couldn't find anything for my question. Or perhaps I'm missing the obvious...